# can't point to right location in compass Swift ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, location, compass

I am developing a compass that can point from my current location to other location, but  after implementing it, I noticed that it always points to the same direction every time of choosing a new target location to go or to point.

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let heading = newHeading.magneticHeading
    let headingR = Measurement(value: newHeading.trueHeading, unit: UnitAngle.degrees).converted(to: .radians).value

    // To know if the Data that our device is correct, The "horizontalAccuracy" value should be grater then ZERO for valid GPS coordinate Data
    if heading < 0 {return}
    // Get the heading(direction)
    if(heading == -1){
        print("no location")
    }
    self.directionAngel = Double(self.getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(latDestination: self.desiredLatit,lonDestination: self.desiredLongit))

    let north = -1 * heading.degreesToRadians
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(north))
        self.directionArrowView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(self.directionAngel.degreesToRadians - headingR))
    }
    self.updateHeading(heading: heading)
}


  private  func getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(latDestination:Double,lonDestination:Double) -> Double {
      
    let lat1 = getMyLocation().latitude.degreesToRadians
    let lon1 = getMyLocation().longitude.degreesToRadians
    
    let lat2 = latDestination.degreesToRadians
    let lon2 = lonDestination.degreesToRadians
    
      let dLon = lon2 - lon1
      let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
      let x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon)
      var radiansBearing = atan2(y, x)
      if(radiansBearing < 0.0){
          radiansBearing += 2 * Double.pi
      }
    return radiansBearing
  }
let locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    $0.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    $0.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    $0.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    $0.startUpdatingLocation()
    $0.startUpdatingHeading()
    return $0
}(CLLocationManager())
```

Comment: You're going to need to debug your code. Log the location points you are receiving. Make sure the location coordinates are correct. Then log the heading values you are computing. Do the same math manually and make sure your heading values match your expected values. Try destination points at various angles around the compass and make sure the results are correct. If everything is good up to that point, it's time to debug the way you're drawing your compass.

Comment: i did all of these more than once  and back to the first state